# Use pre-built static library on ROS2

Tags: ros2, external-libraries

I have a .a file for an SDK for a LIDAR sensor I am planning to use. This .a was given to my company along the .h files, and I would like to wrap it all up on a ROS2 package so I can have a clean separation of their code and examples from my use case.

I have succesfully created a package we can call lidarbrand_decoder, and a package of my own called lidarbrand_publisher. I can include the .h files from the decoder just right on the publisher, and if I use `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} full_path_to_the_file.a)` it builds alright, but I do not know how to do this on a more robust way.

Answer (score 0):

I see two approaches here:

1. Create a separate directory in your `lidarbrand_publisher` for 3rd-party libraries (`3rd`, for example). Move your SDK headers and binary to that dir. So now to reference them in the CMakeLists.txt you can do something like: `{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/3rd/sdk.a`
2. Make a `.deb` package out of the provided SDK files and provision it to the system with the other robot software. Here is a good [howto](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/build-binary-deb-package-practical-guide) guide.

The first one is quicker to implement but is less scalable (what if you need to link the SDK lib to a different package?). So consider the second one if you want the solution to be valid in the long-term.

Comment: Option 1 does not do what I want. I need the package with the static library to export it to the rest of them, not to live inside each package that needs it. I believe this can be done via ROS because I've seen people discussing building their own .a files, but I haven't found a way to do it with pre-built ones. 

Option 2 is unfortunately not possible due to some environment limitations.